# Scala Templating Can't use List[E]

Tags: playframework-2.0

```
@(magazinelist:List[models.Magazine])
@import utils._
```

This is what I'm trying to use, but it does not work. intelliJ tells List "the reference must be prefixed" and the second line also doesn't work (I copied from the Play documentation)

But if I use this:

```
@(magazinelist:util.List[models.Magazine])
@import java.util
```

Although this will not cause an error, I am a bit confused. Is List not a datatype scala supports? Why do I have to use util.List to invoke it?? This looks kinda ugly. Also, if List is not supported so well, what datatype should I choose? Is there a preferable one?

Comment: Use `Seq` instead of `List`.

Comment: Do they work interchangeably?

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you have two types of List: `java.util.List` and `List` (from Scala's functionnal Collections). You should try to convert from one to another with .asScala (from `scala.collection`)